# QGIS - QField - Retrieve target field value when source feature intersects target feature in target layer

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qfield, qfieldsync

I have a simple project in `QGIS 3.10.5`: a polygon layer and a point layer. When the user add a point feature which intersects a polygon feature, a calculate field make this intersection and get the id attribute of the polygon feature.

In my desktop project, I used [refFunctions](https://github.com/enricofer/refFunctions) extension, and result is ok. I have a calculate field in my point layer with an expression: `geomintersects('polygonLayer', 'polygonID')`.

I deployed this project in [QField](https://qfield.org/docs/en/project-management/index.html) and `refFunctions` isn't working anymore, even when `geopackage` is synchronised with desktop project. I tried an other expression without using, `refFunctions` but it's not working better.

```
aggregate(
layer:= 'polygonLayer',
aggregate:='concatenate',
expression:=polygonID,
concatenator:=', ',
filter:=intersects($geometry, geometry(@parent))
)
```

How to calculate an intersection between two layers (and get an attribute value) with `QField`?

Can I use a "native" `QGIS` function to make this intersection in a calculate field? (without using [aggregate](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html#aggregates-functions) because my field is an integer id)

-- EDIT

In my point layer, I also have a date field wich have a default value `format_date( now(),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')`. When I add a feature in QField, date is well calculated and displayed in the form but aggregate function result isn't. When I synchronize my layer with `QFieldSync`, date value is ok but my intersection field with aggregate function is `NULL`.

How to explain this? Both are functions, why behaviours are different?

[Documentation](https://qfield.org/docs/en/project-management/vector-layers.html#id1) seems to indicate, this should works, maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<s>refFunctions won't work in QField as it is a QGIS desktop plugin (and is the downside of the many answers that rely on a plugin for expression-based solutions) - QField won't recognise the functions.</s>

With your aggregate expression, consider using `expression:=to_string("polygonID")` if the `polygonID` field is numeric, as concatenate only works on string values.

**Note 2021-08**: Above is now outdated as QField from at least version 1.8 onwards supports QGIS 3.16 expressions which does include the ported version of refFunctions - `overlay_intersects()`, `overlay_within()` etc. Please use these instead as they are much more elegant!

e.g. `array_to_string(overlay_intersects('polygonLayer',"polygonID"))`

The rest of this answer is more about handling the expression when layer names have changed for whatever reason.

---

If your expression isn't working because the underlying field name has changed, you have two options:

## Option 1: Use Layer ID

You can obtain the layer ID in the Expression window under Map Layers; double-click the layer you want.

[image]

Although the layer ID contains the original filename in front the reference stays the same even if you change the layer name. The example below shows two aggregate expression inside the point labels, one using the layer ID for the line layer, the other using the layer name (initially named `tr_road`).

When I change the layer name the expression using the layer ID still evaluates, but the expression using the layer name fails completely (which was probably what happened to you)

[image]

---

## Option 2: Test for valid layer name

The downside to layer IDs is that they are unique each layer in a project. If your aggregate expression is designed to always pick up a **specifically named layer** but you expect it to refer to *any* potential layer with that name (including a layer you might add later, or another layer renamed accordingly), it won't work.

To catch these errors you can use `try()` to return a value or attempt a different expression if the original expression fails. The expression below returns 'Layer not found' as a text string. You can make it NULL or an empty string if you don't want anything to display.

`try(array_to_string(overlay_intersects('polygonLayer',"polygonID")),'Layer not found')`

Alternatively, if your layer name change is predictable and your `overlay_intersects()` (or `aggregate()`) expression only needs to look at one of two options, try the following expression to use either `layer name` or `layer name (offline)`

```
try(
aggregate(
layer:= coalesce(layer_property('polygonLayer','name'),
                 layer_property('polygonLayer (offline)','name')),
aggregate:='concatenate',
expression:=to_string("polygonID"),
concatenator:=', ',
filter:=intersects($geometry, geometry(@parent))
), 'Layer not found')
```

or for QGIS 3.16 onwards:

```
try(
    array_to_string(
       overlay_intersects(coalesce(layer_property('polygonLayer','name'),
                                   layer_property('polygonLayer (offline)','name')),
                      "polygonID"),
                ','),
  'Layer not found')
```

For more complex cases where you want it to pick the first of a potentially long list of layer names, consider using `with_variable()` and array functions instead, so you can more easily edit your list at the top of your expression and add/remove items easily. I have put that expression in the relevant GitHub discussion thread [here](https://github.com/opengisch/QField/issues/734#issuecomment-623047958).

[image]

Comment: Ok, thanks. It's ok with this expression. I have also delete the concatenator, which is, in my case, not used. An other issue, wich maybe deserve a new post : in QGIS side, attributes default calculated value is well displayed when I identify my feature by clicking on it, but is `NULL` in the attributes table... am I missing something ?

Comment: I have edited my original post to be more specific.

Comment: I get it : I use `QFieldSync` to synchronyze my layer, and this plugin rename layer with a `(offline)` suffix, so in QField aggregate functions can't find this layer named without this suffix in my expression. When I change aggregate function with `polygonLayer (offline)`, everything is ok. Hope this will rectified one day. Thanks to this [post](https://github.com/opengisch/QField/issues/734).

Comment: I have updated the answer with a potential solution to your invalid layer name problem with `aggregate()` - it has been something that has bugged me before as well

Comment: Great, thank your for this feedback. Both methods are functionals.

Comment: How did you make those animations?

Comment: @Taras - I use a software called ScreenToGif on Windows. I'm sure there are similar programs for other OSes.

Comment: Pssst, refFunctions are now in QGIS and QField ;-)
If you want to update your answer ... Here's all you need: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/38405

Answer (score 2):

Great news, the last release of [`QFieldSync`](https://github.com/opengisch/qfieldsync/releases/tag/v3.4.0) preserve the layer name without (offline) suffix. I made a quick test with `aggregate` function and `coalesce` isn't needed anymore, values are well calculated with the original layer name.

Comment: This requires QGIS 3.16.1 or newer