# QField - Display attributes table frame in pdf with editing offline mode

Tags: qgis-3, qfield, qfieldsync

I'm using `QField` and `QFieldSync` to synchronize my data. In a project I build a composer with an attribute table frame, wich show attributes of my layer. When I run the project in `QField` and create a pdf, attribute table is empty.

I have noticed that attributes are well displayed in pdf table frame when `QFieldSync` configuration is set on "Copy" for my layer but not on "Editing offline".

[`QFieldSync` rename layers with a "(offline)" suffix](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/360295/qgis-qfield-retrieve-target-field-value-when-source-feature-intersects-targe), and I think this could be the reason, so I tried to put an expression to deal with this but without success. I found options in `dataDefinedProperties` for this `LayoutObject` like `dataDefinedAttributeTableSourceLayer` but I don't know how to manipulate it.

How to show attributes table frame with `QField` and `QFieldSync` in editing offline mode ?

Is it posible to precise an expression in attribute table frame source layer properties (as specified in [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/composer_items/composer_attribute_table.html#main-properties)) to prevent this ?

Comment: yep, I can't get data-defined override to work for the attribute table either in QGIS 3.10.5 or 3.12.2, even with a simple string value. The layer reference in the main dropdown box is always persistent (even if the layer name is changed), that behaviour may be in conflict with the data defined override. Perhaps you might want to lodge it as an issue on the main QGIS github if nobody else has solutions

Comment: I opened an [issue](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/36195) in QGIS Github